# SQL IN clause ORDER

Tags: sql, soql

This is the current situation:

```
string[] ListOfStrings = ("A","B","C");
record[] v = [SELECT fieldA, fieldB FROM TableX WHERE fieldB IN : ListOfStrings];
```

Ideally I want the returned list "v" ordered as per "ListOfStrings";

so that `"v[0].fieldB" is == "A";`

Instead I get "v" sorted randomly;

Comment: There is no inherent ordering in a SQL resultset unless you specify with an *order by* clause.

Comment: that is what the ORDER BY clause is for in SQL... select ... from .... where .,, ORDER BY FieldB

Answer (score 0):

SQL let us manage the custom order. One approach is using `Case` Statement you can do it.

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB
FROM TableX 
ORDER BY Case fieldB
              When 'A' Then 1
              When 'B' Then 2
              When 'C' Then 3
         END
         -- second order can be add here for example :
         , fieldA
```

It means all record which their value of `fieldB` equals `'A'` come first and so on. For sorting record with same order add another order instead of comment at the end of  query.

Comment: Note that SQL uses single quotes for string literals. Double quotes are for delimited identifiers.

Comment: Yes, some products do things in their own, non-standard way.